# WDS HtmlWebpackPlugin not work with directory back

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

If my directory structure is:

```
/dist
--some.html
--some.css
--some.js
--another.html
--another.css
--another.js
/src
--...
webpack.config.babel.js
```

everything is OK, but if structure is:

```
/dist
--/public
----some.css
----some.js
----another.css
----another.js
--some.html
--another.html
/src
--...
webpack.config.babel.js
```

Any changes in html files are not reflecting even after manually reload page.

**My robust config for the first directory structure case:**

```
...

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index/index',
        contacts: './src/contacts/contacts',
        about: './src/about/about',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "[name].js",
        library: "[name]"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.css', '.scss'],
    },
    resolveLoader: { 
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader" }) },
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
    ]
};

if (NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    let htmlPlugins = [];
    for(let entry in module.exports.entry) {
        htmlPlugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: [`${entry}`],
                filename: `${entry}.html`,
                template: `${module.exports.entry[entry]}.html`,
            })
        );
    }
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat(htmlPlugins);
}
```

**And config for the last case:**

```
...

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index/index',
        contacts: './src/contacts/contacts',
        about: './src/about/about',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/public/"),
        publicPath: "/public/",
        filename: "[name].js",
        library: "[name]"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.css', '.scss'],
    },
    resolveLoader: { 
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader" }) },
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
    ]
};

if (NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    let htmlPlugins = [];
    for(let entry in module.exports.entry) {
        htmlPlugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: [`${entry}`],
                filename: `../${entry}.html`,
                template: `${module.exports.entry[entry]}.html`,
            })
        );
    }
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat(htmlPlugins);
}
```

**As you can see in the last case HtmlWebpackPlugin filename contain directory back (`../${entry}.html`,).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack doesn't let you traverse back from the `output.path` folder. The configuration which should work for your use-case is -

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
      "public/index": './src/index/index',
      "public/contacts": './src/contacts/contacts',
      "public/about": './src/about/about',
  },
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js",
      library: "[name]"
  },

  resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.css', '.scss'],
  },
  resolveLoader: { 
      modules: ['node_modules'],
      extensions: ['.js']
  },

  module: {
      rules: [
          { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/},
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader" }) },
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("public/[name].css"),
  ]
};

if (NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    let htmlPlugins = [];
    for(let entry in module.exports.entry) {
        htmlPlugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: [`${entry}`],
                filename: `${entry}.html`,
                template: `${module.exports.entry[entry]}.html`,
            })
        );
    }
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat(htmlPlugins);
}
```

What we are doing here is that we are providing the sub-path information in the entry name itself. So when webpack generates the output files, it puts them inside those sub-paths. For the htmls, we don't give a sub-path, so they are generated in the root output folder.
This is not foolproof though, you may face issues with webpack-dev-server, or dynamic imports (`require.ensure`) for example. For more details, see this - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189.

Comment: Thank you very much! For me it`s work fine, even require.ensure.